# Need to decode 16-bit unsigned big-endian bytes into integers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pack, endianness

Is there a simple function I can copy and paste to make this conversion? The Ruby equivalent would be

```
bytes.unpack("n*")
```

Comment: You can use `optional p` instead of `fmap Just p <|> return Nothing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `cereal` or `binary` package, decode into a 16 bit unsigned int (`Word16`) then convert that value to a full `Integer`:

```
import Data.Serialize
...
someFunction = ...
    let intVal = runGet (fromIntegral `fmap` getWord16be) bytes
```

Edit:

As with any monad in haskell, you can use higher level function such as `replciateM` along with the above code to get a list of int values (untested code follows):

```
import Data.Serialize
...
someFunction = ...
    let intVals = runGet (do n <- get
                             replicateM n (fromIntegral `fmap` getWord16be)) bs
```

Comment: How would I run runGet to produce a list of [Integer], and not just a single parsed value?

Comment: Have you heard of `replicateM`?

Comment: OK the replicateM strategy works if you know how many times you want to iterate, but what if you don't? `n <- get` doesn't return that number.

Comment: OK I figured out a way using Control.Applicative.(<|>) I copied my solution above.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Based on Thomas M. DuBuisson's suggestions, here's my solution:

```
eitherIntVal :: B.ByteString -> Either String [Integer]
eitherIntVal = runGet (do 
    xs <- replicateM 5 (Just `fmap` getWord16be <|> return Nothing)
    return $ map fromIntegral $ catMaybes xs)
```